# Getting error "nil pointer evaluating interface {}.overwrite" with certificate section using gloo dvpe-helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I am receiving the following error using ArgoCD when defining my certificate section when using the helm chart dvpe-helm: https://github.com/DVPE-cloud/dvpe-helm

> Error: template: dvpe-helm/templates/certificate.yaml:6:24: executing
> "dvpe-helm/templates/certificate.yaml" at
> <.Values.release.overwrite.name>: nil pointer evaluating interface
> {}.overwrite

My certificate section in my repository looks like this:

```
# -------------------------------------#
# Certificate value section            #
# -------------------------------------#
  certificate:
    commonName: cert.api.net
    secretName: private-tls-by-issuer
    issuerRef:
      name: certificate-issuer
      group: controller-manager.dvpe-cloud.github.io
      kind: Issuer
      subject:
        organizations: {}
        countries: {}
        localities: {}
        provinces: {}
        organizationalUnits: {}
        emailAddresses: {}
        dnsNames:
          - gloo-system.api.net
          # Note: We just added this domain to have a handy name for our auth-flows example.
          - auth-flows.api.net
```

I am relatively new to this and I really cannot make anything out of this error message. It does not tell me anything about what is going wrong. Anyone having an idea of what to do with this?

I checked my yaml file and it is valid.

Answer (score -1):

A nil pointer indicates that the value doesn't exists. In your case please search through your chart to find where .Values.release.overwrite.name is being used.

Next, the nil pointer could be due to two cases

1. The hierarchy .Values.release.overwrite.name is not defined in your values file
2. If .Values.release.overwrite.name is present in your values then this means the "." you're using to access Values is not the one you expect it to be.

For example .Values.release.overwrite.name

1. is accessed inside a **range(loop)**, then "." refers to the current item in the iteration, this would throw you off, as .Values.release.overwrite.name would no longer exist in your current iteration item
2. Similarly if you are using  **"with"** block then the "." would mean the item which you tried to lookup using "with"

So based on these please check how .Values.release.overwrite.name is being used and correct the context of "."

You can use different ways to make sure you are accessing the right value by

1. $ which references the global scope in order to access the Values as expected $.Values.release.overwrite.name
2. Assign the value to a variable and use the variable instead

All these options would depend on how the .Values.release.overwrite.name is being used in your chart

Take a look at https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/ for more details